# Is it possible to install and use OpenRasta without IIS? If so, how?

Tags: rest, openrasta

Is it possible to install and use [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta) without IIS?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [thread provides](https://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/ad9bcb7665998520?fwc=1) an example of an HTTPListenerHost

1. Create Console Project
2. Add OpenRasta references
3. Add Initial code from thread
4. Wrap using(OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual) around the contents of the Configure() function

Answer (score 1):

Look at the various examples online about using the httplistener host for usingthe http.sys integration. You can also run it in-memory for unit testing, look at the inmemoryhost classes.

An of course you can implement your own hosting if u need.

Comment: I am still looking for examples online.  We are currently using HTTPListener, (but not RESTfully) so I am (more) familiar with this, but I haven't yet seen an example of using OpenRasta with HTTPListener.  I'll continue looking.

Comment: Don't hesitate to contribute a page or a link in the wiki, it would be good to bring this back to the documentation!

Comment: Are you moving the documentation and the source to github or just the source?

Comment: We're moving everything to github, slowly but surely :)